# Unable to identify elements in a specific page, using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, forms, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I am working on a banking application which has Frames and Forms. I was able to identify webelements from Page 1 and 2. In Page 3, none of the webelements are identified. Am I missing something. Please help. Attached image of DOM Explorer[image]

```
     //page 1 - able to identify WebElements and navigating to Page 2

    driver.switchTo().frame("iframeContent");        
    Select bank = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("selectRegionID")));
    bank.selectByVisibleText("460 - TEST BANK 460");

    driver.findElement(By.id("buttonOK")).click();      
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    //page 2 - able to identify WebElements
    driver.switchTo().frame("iframeContent");       
    driver.findElement(By.id("tdConsumerSearch")).click();
    //driver.switchTo().parentFrame(); //didn't make any difference with and without this line
    Thread.sleep(3000);


    //page 3 - unable to locate any WebElement(tried List/Button/Editbox).
    driver.switchTo().frame("iframeContent");   
    //driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("iframeContent"))); --> Got this from other source, even this line didn't work

    Select bank1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("selectBankID")));
    bank1.selectByVisibleText("ABC Bank");      //unable to perform this operation in page 3
```

**Error Log:**
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == *[name='selectBankID']
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DT-4K3XT12', ip: '10.2.29.106', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:18939/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 6ca654cf-ad3a-4be0-b758-08fb70be1138
*** Element info: {Using=name, value=selectBankID}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:404)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:284)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at com.test.pkg.Sample.main(Sample.java:102)

Comment: Can you please share the error log you are getting?

Comment: @Naveen, added Error Log

Comment: Did the linked answers help you? If not, is that element hidden before and becomes visible after clicking something?

Comment: Linked answers didn't help. I resolved it. I had used one frame in my code. when I analysed DOM till the root, I saw my frame is inside another frame. So, I used two switchTo frames and it worked. Thanks for asking.